# Linq to SQL with UDF - paging exception

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Good day. I got some table result UDF in my **MS SQL 2008R2** base and some mapped class "ApplicationGroupsResult"

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[netsqlazman_ApplicationGroups] ()
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT     dbo.[netsqlazman_ApplicationGroupsTable].*
FROM         dbo.[netsqlazman_ApplicationGroupsTable] INNER JOIN
                      dbo.[netsqlazman_Applications]() Applications ON dbo.[netsqlazman_ApplicationGroupsTable].ApplicationId = Applications.ApplicationId



[Function(Name="dbo.netsqlazman_ApplicationGroups", IsComposable=true)]
public IQueryable<ApplicationGroupsResult> ApplicationGroups()
{
return base.CreateMethodCallQuery<ApplicationGroupsResult>(this, (MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), new object[0]);
}
```

Now I want to take few records:

```
            var query = context.ApplicationGroups();

            totalRecordsCount = query.Count();

            query = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortBy)
                        ? query.OrderBy(x => x.ApplicationGroupId)
                        : query.OrderBy(sortBy);

            return query
                .Skip(pageNumber*queryRecordsCount)
                .Take(queryRecordsCount)
                .ToArray();
```

And I got exception: "This provider supports Skip only over ordered queries returning entities or projections that contain all identity columns, where the query is a single-table (non-join) query, or is a Distinct, Except, Intersect, or Union (not Concat) operation."

Does LinqToSQL with UDF supports paging?
If it do then what I do wrong?

Comment: Why not just use a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - DataContext in library that I used had

```
[Provider(typeof(Sql2000Provider))]
```

So that query would not work without "Distinct" because in sql 2000 there is no Row_number operator and the only way to generate paging query is to use the trick with distinct. 
How LINQ query should be in that case.

```
return query
            .Distinct()
            .Skip(pageNumber*queryRecordsCount)
            .Take(queryRecordsCount)
            .ToArray();
```

I just created my own DataContext and the problem solved:

```
[Provider(typeof(Sql2008Provider))]
public sealed class AzManDataContext : NetSqlAzManStorageDataContext
{
    public AzManDataContext(IDbConnection connection) : base(connection)
    { }
}
```

P.S.

> Here's the problem: "where the query is a single-table (non-join) query".

Table result function in MSSQL handled like a single query so it's correct to use them in paging queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem: "where the query is a **single-table (non-join)** query".

The query in your UDF does an `Inner Join` to another table. In order for `Skip` to work, there must be a pretty "stable" result set to ensure that it can accurately select chunks of it and not pull some random data every time.

By the way, is this UDF just for example purposes? It's something that looks like it can be easily expressed in LINQ in a strongly typed manner, so I have to wonder why you would want this to use a UDF?

Comment: The query doing a join does not matter as L2S cannot know that.